# Difference between: Also, too and as well

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, sentence-ends, also-too

I understand that the correct usage of *also* is with a verb:

> She was smart, she also studied so much.

However, my trouble is with *too* and *as well,* I have been reading and I just found that *as well* is not common in American English, and regarding with the examples that I have found, those adverbs have the same meaning and you can use them in the same way and always at the end of the statement.

> She was smart, she studied so much as well.
>        She was smart, she studied so much too.

How much of that information is true?

Comment: “How much of that information is true?” is not a very good question. It needs to be more concrete. You also have other problems as well, such as a confusingly unidiomatic use of “so much” (whose meaning I cannot quite unravel) — and a comma-splice, too.

Comment: Reading and hearing English is the best way I know to get to know what is typical and common for native speakers and writers.  "Too", "also", "as well", "additionally", are all generally common, with "too" probably being the most informal of the list.  It's been my experience to hear "too" used in more spoken English than in written English.  Have you checked out the English Language Learners site: http://ell.stackexchange.com?

Comment: This looks like a good candidate to be migrated to English Language Learners: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adverbs also, as well and too have similar meanings, but they do not go in the same position in sentences.
Also is usually used with the verb. Too and as well usually go at the end of a sentence or clause. Note that ‘as well’ is not very common in American English.

```
He not only plays; he also works.
He was fat, and he was also short.
He not only plays; he works as well.
He was fat, he was short as well.
He not only plays; he works too.
He was fat, he was short too.
```

Refer [here](http://www.englishpractice.com/vocabulary/also-as-well-and-too/) for more assistance.